# How to query a database with an array? WHERE = 'array()'

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I'm wondering how to query a database using an array, like so:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM status_updates WHERE member_id = '$friends['member_id']'");
```

`$friends` is an array which contains the member's ID.  I am trying to query the database and show all results where `member_id` is equal to one of the member's ID in the `$friends` array.

Is there a way to do something like `WHERE = $friends[member_id]` or would I have to convert the array into a string and build the query like so:

```
$query = "";
foreach($friends as $friend){
  $query .= 'OR member_id = '.$friend[id.' ';
}
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM status_updates WHERE member_id = '1' $query");
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Quick tip: If your `member_id`'s are `INT`'s in the table, don't quote them.

Comment: @webbiedave Yes you **do** quote INTs. MySQL does not magically convert the type of a value to string upon seeing quotes. Quotes designate value start and end. Not having to quote INTs is a much abused feature for lazy typers.

Comment: @Mel: You are definitely in the minority on that one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want [`IN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in).

```
SELECT * FROM status_updates WHERE member_id IN ('1', '2', '3');
```

So the code changes to:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM status_updates WHERE member_id IN ('" . implode("','", $friends) . "')");
```

Depending on where the data in the friends array comes from you many want to pass each value through `mysql_real_escape_string()` to make sure there are no SQL injections.

Answer (score 0):

Use the SQL IN operator like so:

```
// Prepare comma separated list of ids (you could use implode for a simpler array)
$instr = '';
foreach($friends as $friend){
    $instr .= $friend['member_id'].',';
}
$instr = rtrim($instr, ','); // remove trailing comma
// Use the comma separated list in the query using the IN () operator
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM status_updates WHERE member_id IN ($instr)");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM status_updates WHERE ";
for($i = 0 ; $i < sizeof($friends); $i++){
$query .= "member_id = '".$friends[$i]."' OR ";
}
substr($query, -3);
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: implode would be more appropriate for this activity, which is suspect to begin with - an IN would be better.