# How to use an array to query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is there any way I can use the array from $query and use it in another query like the $query2 below? It works but it only returns the first data of the array...

Already tried these links already but none of them worked in my case
[Array in SQL Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295714/array-in-sql-query)

[How to query a database with an array? WHERE = 'array()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971793/how-to-query-a-database-with-an-array-where-array)

```
$query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM patient_details WHERE discharged_date >= '2019-03-01' AND discharged_date < '2019-03-30'");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $result = $row['hosp_patient_no'];
        $query2 = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT deficiencies_id FROM deficiency_patient_details WHERE hosp_patient_no = '$result'");

}
```

Comment: Unless there is a specific reason, I would look to combine the two queries into 1 SQL statement.

Comment: You have to use a column I'm not entirely sure it's possible to compare two arrays in SQL however, you could compare them in PHP using two queries

Comment: It's generally a bad idea. Just use a JOIN instead.

Comment: I'm actually going to use the array to query again. After $query2, I'll query again using that array.

Answer (score 0):

you are using mysqli_fetch_array which will "Fetches a result row as an associative, a numeric array, or both", but your requirement says it otherwise so you should use mysqli_fetch_all which "Fetches all result rows as an associative array, a numeric array, or both".

so your syntax should look like this

```
$query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM patient_details WHERE discharged_date >= '2019-03-01' AND discharged_date < '2019-03-30'");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_all($query)){
    $result = $row['hosp_patient_no'];
    $query2 = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT deficiencies_id FROM deficiency_patient_details WHERE hosp_patient_no = '$result'");
```

}

infact i would suggest you to do this in a single query using subquery.

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_all()` will return all rows in 1 call, which also means `$row['hosp_patient_no']` will be incorrect - `$row[0]['hosp_patient_no']` will be needed to use the value from the first row.

Comment: yes, i missed that one, actually i copied whole code from question and forgot..  oops. :)

Comment: undefined index :/